# How to make a script on a prefab act on a particular scene instance?

Tags: unity, c#, events

I am building Actionables (Windmill, Coal) on a Planet by hovering the mouse over the Planet and clicking on it.

[image: my setup]

Actionables are prefabs, which have an `Actionable` component, with the same setup (at the moment).

[image: actionable]

Once the player is happy with the location of their Actionable, they click LMB, which activates `onClick` callback, which is supposed to call `Planet.Build()`, which adds the Actionable on the Planet permanently (saves it into an internal array).

I also have a "Turn Off" Button, which calls `stopBuilding()` when clicked, disabling the preview placement.

When `stopBuilding()` is invoked by the button click, everything works as expected.

I also want to be able to call `Planet.stopBuilding()` (which, by removing the `actionableModel`, disables hover preview on the Planet) from `Planet.Build()`, such that the player does not need to click the Turn Off button described above after building an Actionable.

Inside Actionable prefabs I can only assign other prefabs, but I need them to interact with the scene object. I cannot override the Planet object in Actionable instances, as they are generated on the fly.

How do I access the scene object Planet from Actionable prefab?

Here is my `Planet` and its `stopBuilding` method so far:

```
   public class Planet : MonoBehaviour
   {
       private GameObject actionableModel;

       // ...

       public void stopBuilding()
       {
           // For debugging only
           Planet planet = GameObject.Find("Planet").GetComponent<Planet>();
           Debug.Log(planet.actionableModel);
           Debug.Log(this.actionableModel);

       }
   }
```

And here is the `Actionable` component which has a `UnityEvent` property `onClick`, which calls `stopBuilding()` on a click event.

```
   public class Actionable : MonoBehaviour
   {
       public class OnClick : UnityEvent<GameObject> { }
       public OnClick onClick = new OnClick();

       // ...

       void OnMouseDown()
       {
           onClick.Invoke(gameObject);
       }
   }
```

Comment: Your button probably will stop working correctly as well as soon as you have two planets in the scene. `stopBuilding` is already on the Planet Component if I understand your code correctly, therefore the line `GameObject.Find("Planet").GetComponent<Planet>();` will always look exactly the Object in your scene called Planet and can't find a second one even if it is called Planet as well.

Comment: @Zibelas Yeah, that is true, that is why I wanted to avoid GameObject.Find, it is there just for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I want to challenge this:

> I cannot override the Planet object in Actionable instances, as they are generated on the fly.

They are being generated on the fly *by your code*. So, *your code* can provide the correct `Planet` instance.

```
Actionable SpawnActionablePrefab(Actionable prefab, Planet planetToBuildOn) {
    var instance = Instantiate(prefab);

    // TODO: Position/rotate it as desired or perform other setup steps.

    
    instance.OnClick.AddListener(() => planet.StopBuilding(instance.gameObject));

    return instance;
}
```

You could use this same approach to assign the current planet to a member variable on the instance at spawn time, so it has a local record of who to call later, in case you want to avoid constructing delegates all the time.

So be wary of the temptation to throw up your hands and say "I can't" - chances are, you *can*.

---

That said, I think there are other approaches that are more scalable - especially if you want to grow your game to support multiple planets, pooling actionables, etc. in the future.

We could introduce a `SelectionManager` whose job it is to keep track of which planet the player is currently interacting with.

```
public class SelectionManager : MonoBehaviour {

    // Quick & dirty singleton pattern with lazy instantiation,
    // so it works even if you don't have an instance in your scene.
    static SelectionManager _instance;
    public static SelectionManager Instance {
        get {
            if (_instance == null) {
                _instance = FindObjectOfType<SelectionManager>();
                if (_instance == null) {
                    var manager = new GameObject("Selection Manager");
                    _instance = manager.AddComponent<SelectionManager>();
                }
            }

            return _instance;
        }
    }

    Planet _selectedPlanet;

    void Awake() {
        // Assign a default selection.
        // Replace this with your actual selection logic when the time comes.
        _selectedPlanet = FindObjectOfType<Planet>();
    }

    public Planet GetSelectedPlanet() { return _selectedPlanet; }

    public void SetSelectedPlanet(Planet planet) { 
        // TODO: you might want to call on OnSelect / OnDeselect here,
        // or abort up any UI operations currently in progress on the selected planet.
        _selectedPlanet = planet; 
    }
}
```

Now inside `Actionable` we can have a method like this:

```
public void Finish() {
    SelectionManager.Instance.GetSelectedPlanet().StopBuilding(gameObject);
}
```

Your `OnClick` event on the prefab can now call *its own* `Finish()` method. When this is invoked on an instance of the prefab at runtime, it will query the `SelectionManager` to ask for the currently selected planet so that it can route its call to it correctly.

So the prefab doesn't need any references to the scene object when it's sitting in your assets folder. We'll fetch that information on demand.

Comment: This is a great answer. I have independently come up with a similar approach, but yours is so much more comprehensive and flexible. Thank you so much!